# Приложение работает в дебаг режиме, а в релизе - segmentation fault. В чем может быть дело?

Tags: c++, qt, отладка

Есть приложение, если его запустить в дебаг режиме, то всё нормально, если скомпилить и запустить в релизе, то происходит краш, "сигментэйшин фаулт".
Сомневаюсь, что дело в коде.

Comment: Дело именно в коде, ищите проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блочная тестировка кода путём комментирования разных строк показала ошибку, уже исправил, странное дело, обычное использование объекта с потерей его инициализацией и выделение памяти под него(забыл за ньюить), почему дебаг пропускал такую ошибку до сих пор для меня загадка.

Answer (score 5):

Нет-нет, дело как раз в коде. Некоторые дебаггеры обладает странной особенностью — постоянно выделяется памяти на стеке больше, чем просят. В результате ошибки с выходом за границы выделенной памяти в функциях  нередко остаются незаметными. К тому же, в режиме дебага часто переменные и указатели автоматически инициализируются нулями, что также скрывает ошибку, когда программист забывает самостоятельно поставить значение.

Что делать? Во-первых, просмотреть свой код на предмет упомянутых ошибок. Во-вторых, вынести всю работу с массивами, указателями в пару-тройку методов, где всегда проверять индекс, если это ещё не сделано.

Кстати, советую запастись юнит-тестами, Qt к ним располагает. В релиз-сборке как раз можно будет найти все ошибки. На Хабре есть [статья по теме](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146449/).

Comment: Интересное дело, самое интересное до этого такого не было и тот кусок кода я не трогал, в котором щас это происходит...

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко ну-с, такого рода ошибки в коде как раз и приводят к последствиям, которые не всегда проявляются, а как призраки в фильмах, иногда выскакивают и пугают... Остаётся лишь инкапсулировать критический код со всеми проверками и отлаживать его юнит-тестами.

Comment: Спасибо, за совет с юнит тестами, почитаю, по разбираюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Выяснилось, что в конструкторе не выделяется память, но проверка указателя не производится. Ошибка где-то в коде самой библиотеки.

Пришлось полностью переписывать приложение таким образом, чтобы вместо например

```
class MyWidget {
   QWidget childWidget;
};
```

было

```
class MyWidget {
   QWidget* pChildWidget;
   MyWidget() {
      pChildWidget = new QWidget();
      if (pChildWidget == nullptr)
         throw MyException("Can't create pChildWidget.");
   }
};
```

Comment: Советую использовать не 0, а `nullptr`, это идёт по стандарту  C++11, чтобы его использовать в *.pro добавьте `CONFIG += c++11`

Comment: Дело было в 2010-м =)

Comment: Вот не надо таких советов. Если ошибка и правда в библиотеке - то надо идти и чинить библиотеку, а не костыли пристраивать.

Comment: Так библиотека собрана в бинарник, как её чинить прикажете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov это совет по стилю, а не по использованию данной библиотеки, ибо nullptr это специализированная константа, которая не факт, что будет равно целочисленному нулю в используемой системой, да и неявное приведение типов не лучшая идея.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко для указателей 0 будет преобразован во что надо компилятором. nullptr - это просто шаблон, который возвращает 0 при приведении к типу указателя.

Comment: По поводу же бинарника - ну так достаньте исходники...

Comment: Речь идёт о библиотеке Qt. Если моё приложение не работает, то это не проблема библиотеки, а проблема моего приложения. Тем более, что после переделки всё стало работать как надо.

Меня не устраивал вариант распространять исходники Qt вместе с моим приложением. Мне требовалось, чтобы моё приложение работало с той версией Qt, которая установлена у пользователя. Так что править исходники библиотеки - это однозначно не вариант.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну понятное дело, что 0 == (int)nullptr, но стандарт для того и создан, чтобы пользоваться им. "Причина введения nullptr в язык С++ заключается в устранение возможных недоразумений между литералом 0 как целочисленным значением и указателем. Двойное значение литерала 0 может вызывать проблемы при некоторых обстоятельствах. Литерал nullptr имеет тип std::nullptr_t, и его нельзя перепутать со значением другого типа. Он может быть неявно преобразован в любой ссылочный тип, но ни в один целочисленный тип, кроме типа bool." - Айвор Хортон, Visual C++ 2010, Глава 4 *примечание.

Comment: @ВячеславСавченко эти самые "проблемы" возникают только при использовании шаблонов. Сравнение указателя с 0 и с nullptr - полностью эквивалентно.