# Почему не инициализированная переменная класса в Release равно 0, а в Debug это случайное число(мусор)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-7

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    int m_n;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
    }

    MyClass(int arg) 
    {
        m_n = arg;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << m_n << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.show();
}
```

Visual Studio 2015 (C++11), x64, Windows7 x64

Release: 0

Debug  : -89654789

Comment: Обращение к неинициализированной переменной является неопределенным поведением. Тут нельзя говорить даже  о том, что код `cout << m_n << endl;` вообще выполняется и печатает значение `m_n`.

Comment: Потому, что ноль это тоже случайное число, которое попадает в m_n. Если переменная не инициализировалась, то надеятся на что либо без смысленно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже было подмечено в комментариях, без инициализации переменная может иметь *любое* значение, которое может зависеть от чего угодно. Это один из примеров **неопределённого поведения** (*undefined behaviour*) ([статья с описанием на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)), и этого нужно всячески избегать.

---

**Почему в дебаге 0?**

Дебаггеры обладают определёнными чертами, которые иногда скрывают неопределённое поведение. Например, самостоятельно инициализируют переменные нулями. Или же [выделяют памяти больше, чем просишь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/520621/198251), из-за чего бывает незаметна ошибка выхода за границы массива.

Опять же, главный вопрос здесь должен быть не *"почему происходит так и не иначе?"* (ответ на который может зависеть от конкретных библиотек, компилятора и т.д), а *"как этого избежать?"*. В данном случае – всегда самому инициализировать переменные и не считывать их без этого.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, я конечно же понимаю некоторые нюансы  неопределённого поведения (undefined behaviour), и очень хорошо понимаю, что нужно инициализировать все возможные переменные до их утилизации, но вопрос был чуть глубже, уточняю "во всех случаях в Release версии переменная была равной 0, и во всех случаях в Debug версии мусор."
Мне интересно понять это зависит от реализации, от компилятора, или от чего то еще, или просто так совпали звезды.

Comment: лучше считать, что просто так совпало.  Попытка глубже понимать уводит нас в очень далекие дали.

Comment: @James я уже написал, что, это всё конечно не просто так, но зависит от многих нюансов – версий библиотек, компилятора и т.д. Потому что разработчики всех этих вещей реализуют один **стандарт языка**, а внутреннее устройство реализаций и отношение к нестандартным ситуациям идут на усмотрение отдельных разработчиков, кому как выгоднее сделать в конкретных условиях. И эти тонкости могут легко поменяться в новых версиях. Поэтому к ним **нужно** относиться как к **случайностям**.

Comment: @James в данном случае очевидно компилятор в Релизе провёл дополнительную работу и выявил переменную без инициализации, сам всё поправил, в отличие от режима Дебага, где важнее скорость запуска кода. На такое поведение не стоит рассчитывать, так как в других компиляторах, (например, Qt) ситуация может быть полностью противоположная.

Comment: @AivanF простите, какой компилятор? А можно ссылку?  Может Вы имели в виду gcc/icc/clang или что-нибудь из этого [списка](http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html)?

Comment: @vegorov в ответе я писал про опыт работы с Desktop Qt 5.6.0 clang 64 bit.

Comment: @AivanF. То есть про clang 64 bit. Qt то тут при чём ?